# Google Play Games fails to find "Public Google+ Profile"`

Tags: google-plus, google-play-games

I created a "Public google+ profile" after the first time it asked me, but it just endlessly asks for this every time I try to launch Google Play Games, or any game that relies on it.

I deleted cache, deleted data, and running short on ideas here.

- Is this something that's known?
- Does my Google+ profile need to be more public?
- Does anyone know the requirements on a Google account for Google Play Games to be able to find it?

Comment: @Firelord ah geeze, everybody's a critic ;P (thanks - though I'm still pondering upping my hipster cred to solve the problem. Maybe some craft beer and suspenders..)